# Why is the endpoints tab not appearing in the microsoft 365 defender console

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am trying to onboard a device to MS 365 defender via the Settings -> Endpoints tab as stated in MSDN, but the tab is not showing up for me. It shows up for other people ive talked to. Is there something I need to do to enable it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please check the below **note** from [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender/microsoft-365-security-center-mde?view=o365-worldwide):

> **What you see in Microsoft 365 Defender depends on your current subscriptions**.

I tried to check the same in my environment and was unable to    find the **Endpoint menu** same as you like below:

[image]

**This issue usually occurs if there is no required license that supports Microsoft 365 Defender.**

Please check the below **link** to know the licensing requirements to access Microsoft 365 Defender:

[Microsoft 365 Defender prerequisites | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender/prerequisites?view=o365-worldwide#licensing-requirements)

- Try to acquire at least **`Microsoft Defender for Endpoint`** license.
- Make sure to sign-in with **admin account** to Microsoft 365 Defender admin center.

*If the issue still persists, please raise [**Azure Support Ticket**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/).*

**References:**

[Endpoint menu missing in security.microsoft.com by Ash Gardiner](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-defender-for-endpoint/endpoint-menu-missing-in-security-microsoft-com/m-p/3021187)

[Onboard devices and configure Microsoft Defender for Endpoint capabilities | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/onboard-configure?view=o365-worldwide)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see the Endpoints tab if you don't have a Defender for Endpoint license.